# How to force a drive letter for a USB drive

Tags: windows-xp

I have a USB drive that i connect to my laptop every morning when i switch it on at work. I have an indexing type applicaiton that indexes files on my laptop and stores them on the USB drive.

I configured the indexing application to save files on drive F: but sometimes when i log on the USB drive is assigned drive D:

I noticed there is an option to change the drive letter under "Computer Management" > Storage > Disk Management but is there a way to make the drive association permanenent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tool is an option:

http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html

Answer (score 2):

If you do that it is relatively permanent.  I say relatively because if another drive takes that letter first then obviously it won't.  The trick is to pick a letter further up the alphabet, far enough that nothing should take it first.  I usually pick letters above `J` for just that reason.