# Windows 7 keeps losing drive letters

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, drive-letter

Windows 7 loses its drive letters and I have to keep manually assigning a drive letter everytime I plug in a hard drive, whether it's internal or external.

The only way to get around it is to reinstall Windows 7 but the problem will come back after a few months. We are a PC repair company and plug in many drives during the say and it can be very frustrating having to keep assigning a drive letter every time a drive is plugged in. Windows Updates are turned off so it can't be that.

Any reason why this would have happened?

Comment: Related: [How to force a drive letter for a USB drive](http://superuser.com/questions/197970/how-to-force-a-drive-letter-for-a-usb-drive)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it probably had to do with the windows saving different drive letters for different drives into its registry. The registry keys are:  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices`

I guess if you delete the unused entries it may help... but you may as well ruin the system and need a reinstall if you somehow messed up with it..

so there you go...

Comment: Thanks for that. Do you know how to find out what the volume id of the current drives installed are so that I do not remove the wrong ones?  http://img.ly/images/629138/full

Comment: c:\> mountvol [enter]

Comment: may i stress once more that it is very dangerous stuff to edit. remember to at least make a restore point/backup beforehand

Comment: OK thanks. Just doing an image before I change anything

Comment: Also read @harrymc's link.. it's a good read

Comment: Hi again. Nope it's still doing the same thing. Grr. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, i think that's what i could think of at the moment... let me think for a while and come back...

Comment: @bubu your comment is a partial answer and you should submit it as such.  I did the following: removed my USB drive; mountvol /R; mountvol /E; inserted my USB drive -- got the typical pop-up to choose what to do (e.g., open in Explorer)

Comment: This fixed my issue, there were a bunch of junk entries in the registry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) to keep my registry all nice and tidy, and as a result, it seems to be wiping the drive letter assignment registry items. While this isn't a solution per se, it seems to me that you may be running into something similar since you're a repair shop and may be trying to keep your test systems squeaky with a daily scheduled registry sweep which could be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that since you are plugging-in so many disks, Windows runs out of drive letters.

When that happens, you can assign the drive letter manually from Computer Management / Disk Management.

If you would like to make Windows forget all drive letter assignments, read this carefully:
[Change or Delete System Drive Letter via Registry to Remove Conflict](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/11/08/change-or-delete-system-drive-letter-via-registry-to-remove-conflict-usb-or-firewire-drive-letter/).

Answer (score 0):

From [Microsoft forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/repeated-loss-of-drive-letter-assignment-upon/6dd6edb7-250e-46c2-9f31-05d4ed5db4a5?tab=question&status=AllReplies):

DOS run diskpart. Sure enough, the volume was perfectly ok, but the "hidden" attribute was set. So a quick

```
LIST VOLIUME

SELECT VOLUME n

ATTRIBUTES VOLUME CLEAR HIDDEN

EXIT
```

Comment: Please add a link to the source.